# Get dial up internet on Windows 7 computer without PCI cards

Tags: windows-7, networking, 64-bit, dial-up

I have just purchased the Dell Zino HD for my grandparents, which is fantastic for their needs. The only problem is that is does not come with a built in 56K dial up modem.

Does anyone know of a good external dial up modem that supports 64bit Windows 7? It does not matter if it connects by USB or ethernet or whatever, it just needs to be simple and easy to use (excluding once off setup).

Comment: no cellphone coverage there? try a 3G first before resorting to 56k analog.

Comment: @Molly, 3G but is more expensive. Currently, they are just getting prepaid dialup at $10, which expires every month. In Australia, the lowest denomination for 3G internet is $30. They don't really use it that much, so spending that much money is unjustified

Comment: if they're happy with dial up and the infrastructure is in good shape, why not. over here even some rather basic websites such as aerlingus.com take about 15-20 minutes to load on a 56k connection. and by the time i'm done booking a flight to Dublin i could have taken the bus :)

Comment: @Molly, It is so horribly painfully slow (and they recognise this), but it is the cheapest option out there, considering how much they use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Zoom%2056K%20V.92%20USB%20Mini%20External%20Modem&v=Zoom&uid=3095F&pf=0&pi=1&c=Networking&sc=Modems&os=64-bit

Here is one listed on the Windows 7 compatibility site. The ZOOM Model 3095F is compatible with 64bit Windows 7.

[image: asd]

- http://www.zoom.com/products/dial_up_external_usb.html (Product link)
- http://www.zoom.com/techsupport/dial_up/3095F.shtml (Links to drivers and documentation)

Answer (score 1):

I have used and loved and recommended [this little guy](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16825134003). Works fine in Win7 32/64bit. I admit I was connected to the net via my home wifi when I set it up for my mother's needs but that is a one off thing. So windows found the driver fine on its own for that.

Answer (score 1):

Hiro Ext. USB 56K V.92 Modem/XP 64 Bit/Vista Ready/RoHS compliant, **Compatible with Windows 7**

[image]

Available at **[tigerdirect.com](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=2539629&CatId=564)** for $29.99