# Internet dial-up, need a modem

Tags: internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get dial up internet on Windows 7 computer without PCI cards](https://superuser.com/questions/100252/get-dial-up-internet-on-windows-7-computer-without-pci-cards)

I am living in a jungle (for working), where there is no cell phone signal or broad band internet, but there is telephone line.

Are there any kind of 56k modem nowadays that works on modern laptops ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few, like [this](http://www.usr.com/products/modem/modem-product.asp?sku=USR5637) external USB modem.